# Can I filter *out* dependabot notifications in GitHub?

Tags: github

[Dependabot](https://github.com/dependabot) is so useful... And so noisy!

I'd love to be able to create a custom filter that shows only non-dependabot notifications in my github Notifications tab.

The documentation says [exclusion is not supported](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/viewing-and-triaging-notifications/managing-notifications-from-your-inbox#custom-filter-limitations) but I suspect I'm not the only one who wishes for a solution so wanted to see if anybody else has found a clever workaround.

Is there any way to only show notifications generated by humans rather than bots?